# Locally integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I believe (although I am not sure) this result is true and wanted to confirm wheather by proof is correct.

> If $A$ is noetherian ring and $p\subset A$ is prime ideal such that $A_p$ is domain, then, there exists an $f\in A$ such that $A_f$ is also a domain.

This is my (hopefully correct) proof:

If $a\subset A$ is the ideal generated by the set of all zero-divisors, then $a_p=0$. Let $x_1,...x_n\in a$ be some generators of $a$. Then, there exists $f_1,...,f_n\in A$ such that $f_ix_i=0$. Thus, if I take $f=\prod f_i$, then $a_f=0$. Then, $A_f$ is domain.

Is there any error in the proof?

I has this question because of a proof of regular implies smoothness in a scheme over a perfect field. In the proof, the author took a locally finite type scheme $X$ over a field $k$ and some closed $x\in X$ and so we have $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a regular local ring. They then reduced the problem to $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ for some domain $A$. Sure, if the above proof is correct, then the reduction is valid.

$\textbf{Update:}$ The above proof is incorrect. The correct proof is in the comments. The idea is to take the kernel of the map $A\rightarrow A_p$ and make it vanish when localising at some $f$.

Comment: I'm not claiming to know either way, but a red flag is that you don't seem to have used the fact that $a_P=0$ in your proof.

Comment: The fact the $a_p=0$ and since the ring is noetherian, I can find the finite $f_i\in A\setminus p$

Comment: The ideal generated by all zero divisors could be the whole ring. Take $a$ in your notation to be just the kernel of the natural map $A\to A_p$.

Comment: No. Take $A$ to be product of two fields, say $k\times k$ and $p=k\times{0}$. Then $A_p$ is a domain, but the ideal generated by all zero divisors is all of $A$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. Your idea of taking $a$ to be the kernel of that map fixes the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can also post the answer as a CW post so that this question gets off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg sorry, but I do not know what that means! If you could explain, I would be glad to do it immediately.